# iFrame blocked due to portocols, domains & ports must match

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am getting the error below:

> Blocked a frame with origin `https://<my host ip>` from accessing a
>   frame with origin `https://<target host ip>`. Protocols, domains, and
>   ports must match.

If you notice both are 'https'. But still the error occurs. Please help - how do I avoid this.

Comment: you need to accept an answer.

Answer (score 8):

As the title says:

```
 domains & ports must match
```

Two different ips, that means you have two different domains.

Read about the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

If you control both domains, you need to look into [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage)

Comment: But then how can I access other domain

Comment: Hackers would love to be able to do it so they can read your email or your bank account. Hence why there is protection. Learn about [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage) in modern day browsers.

Comment: This only happens to me on Safari, which is strange!

Answer (score -1):

**Protocols, domains, and ports must match**

`<my host ip>` is not the same as `<target host ip>`  These are both parts of the domain in the url.

http:// is the Protocol
ip or website name is the domain
:xxxx is the port

so end result: `http://ip:xxxx`