# Uncaught Security Error in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http

Uncaught Security Error: Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.irishotel.in" from accessing a frame with origin "https://maps.google.co.in".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.

Comment: All requests must use HTTPS

Comment: possible duplicate of [iFrame blocked due to portocols, domains & ports must match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18793382/iframe-blocked-due-to-portocols-domains-ports-must-match)

Comment: all requests use https,it is the website domain that is not using https, this problem only occurs in Chrome. How to solve this??