# How to open/use a url having non-standard port within an html iframe?

Tags: php, html, iframe

I am not able to view webpage having the url: `http://www.example.com:9999` from `<iframe>` element, which contain a non-standard port 9999.
And this url (`http://www.example.com:9999`) is accessible from the browser.


Following is the sample html code that I am using:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Iframe test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <iframe src="http://www.example.com:9999" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I am trying to use url having standard port(like: 80) in the `src` attribute `<iframe>`, that works perfectly

So is there any way to use an url having non-standard port in the `src` attribute of a `<iframe>`.

Comment: Just checking: Do you see the page when you use the url with the non standard port number when you just enter it into the browsers address bar?

Comment: yes, the url having the non-standard port is accessible from browser.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to same origin policy, please see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18793382/iframe-blocked-due-to-portocols-domains-ports-must-match).

The port used for the main page & the iframe should be the same. You can get around this using `window.postMessage`